# Android CheckedTextVIew Clear All/Select All

Tags: android, listview, checkedtextview

I have a *ListView* that utilizes a *CheckedTextView* and a clear all button that has the following code:

```
btnClearAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            int listsize = songsList.size();
            filelv = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.FileList);
            checkedCount = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<listsize-1; i++) {
                // if(currentPlayList.get(i).equals ("Checked")){
                songsList.get(i).get("songCheckedStatus").equals("Not Checked");

                filelv.setItemChecked(i, false);
            } 

        }       
    });
```

When the code executes, each array *"songsList"* value is set to *"Not Checked"* correctly, so I know that the button is working.  However, the *CheckedTextView* items are not "unticking".

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If you use a custom adapter then the `setItemChecked` will not work and you'll have to change the status of the `CheckedTextView` at the adapter level.

Comment: Sometimes the solution is so obvious.... If I just pass a variable to the function that builds the listview, before it calls the adapter, I can easily select/clear all.  Thanks for the nudge in the right direction

Comment: If you found the solution, post an answer and accept it so the question will become answered.

Comment: Hi, that's my intention, not tested yet, so will post later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

olution:

As mentioned above, I just set up a global variable and passed whether I wanted to Select All or Clear All to it.  Then I just called my function for populating the ListView.  As the ListView is built, it checks the variable in a simple "if" statement, and adds whether to check or uncheck.  The cursor adapter then does the check/uncheck as it reruns.

```
//The code for clearing all.
btnClearAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkedCount = 0;

            GetMusicMode = "ClearAll";
            GetMusic getMusic = new GetMusic();
            getMusic.execute();
        }       
    });
```

And this from my data grabber for the ListView.

```
 ....
 String track_Title = null;
 String track_Path = null;
 String track_Artist = null;
 String track_Album = null;
 String track_ID = null;
 String track_TrackNumber = null;
 String track_AlbumID = null;
 String track_ArtistID = null;
 String track_Checked = null;

 if (Constants.GetMusicMode.equals("SelectAll")){
track_Checked = "Checked";
}else{
track_Checked = "Not Checked";
 }
 .....

 .....

 HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
song.put("songTitle", track_Title);
song.put("songPath", track_Path);
song.put("songArtist", track_Artist);
song.put("songAlbum", track_Album);
song.put("songTrackNumber", track_TrackNumber);
song.put("songID", track_ID);
song.put("songAlbumID", track_AlbumID);
song.put("songArtistID", track_ArtistID);
song.put("songCheckedStatus", track_Checked);


// Adding each song to SongList
songsList.add(song);

    ....throw to cursor adapter
```

and finally, this section from the cursoradapter getview

```
if (songsList.get(position).get("songCheckedStatus").equals("Checked")){
holder.checkTextView.setChecked(true);
}else{
 holder.checkTextView.setChecked(false); 
}
```

Comment: can you share the code of the adapter. i am trying to do the same with a checkbox at the top on the listview. where checking it and unchecking it should check or uncheck all the checkedtextview